# On production I cant login ASP MVC 5 IDENTITY 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

From my application, inserting the conn string  for my db on cloud, it's work just fine. But when I publish app, deploy on some hosting, I get poreview log in screen, but I cant login (timeout error).

my config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<authentication mode="None" />
<compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234"  newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers"  publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages"  publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory  type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"  type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices,  EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
<!--<appSettings>
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>-->
<!--<appSettings>
<add key="closeModal" value="False"/>
</appSettings>-->
</configuration>
```

I have database called "DB_9F4064_SalesManagement". So I put that databse into Identity Model ApplicationDbContext():

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser

{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string NameSurname { get; set; }
    public string Name
    {
        set
        {
            NameSurname = FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }
        }
}
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DB_9F4064_SalesManagement", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what went wrong?

Should I put more of code? Thanks

Comment: When you publish, do you specify a database connection string?

Comment: Are you sure the user you're trying to login as already exists?

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config, you should have the connection string specified inside the configuration tag. Here is a sample:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="data source=YourDbServerIp;initial catalog=DB_9F4064_SalesManagement;user id=loginUsername;password=loginPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Then your ApplicationDbContext constructor would look like this:

```
public ApplicationDbContext() 
: base("name=ConnectionStringName", throwIfV1Schema: false){}
```